# wsdl Parser using asp .net (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any asp .net (using C#) wsdl parser. I have tired to convert C# .NET wsdlreder to asp .net wsdlreder.

I want parse wsdl url using asp .net application. Just Like service-repository.com website.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't get your question. Try to state what you do now, why it's bad, and what you want to have.

Comment: I am adding Image of WSDL Reader using C#. NET for explanation but it's not allowing to me.

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL parser in WCF is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you I have checked this link. This is in WCF but I want this process in asp .net using c#.

Comment: You can use WCF libraries in ASP.NET.